# UWP CommandBar More Button not showing unless size changed

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

My question is almost the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635723/uwp-commandbar-more-button-not-showing-up-with-dynamicoverflowenabled).

My `CommandBar` is supposed to have these buttons:

```
<CommandBar
    DefaultLabelPosition="Right"
    Style="{StaticResource PlaylistCommandBarStyle}">
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Shuffle"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Add"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Rename"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Pin"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Clear"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Delete"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
</CommandBar>
```

When the window size is not large enough to hold the last delete button, it should go to overflow and then show a More Button instead. However, the more button is not shown unless I resize the window.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635723/uwp-commandbar-more-button-not-showing-up-with-dynamicoverflowenabled) is very complicated. I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

`PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle` is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Dictionaries/PlaylistAppBarButton.xaml).

`PlaylistCommandBarStyle` is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Dictionaries/PlaylistCommandBar.xaml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CommandBar's overflow button has two conditions.

The first is that the screen width is not enough to display the full list of buttons.

The second is that `CommandBar.SecondaryCommands` is not empty.

You can try moving the unimportant buttons into the `SecondaryCommands` list.

```xml
<CommandBar
    DefaultLabelPosition="Right"
    Style="{StaticResource PlaylistCommandBarStyle}">
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Shuffle"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Add"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Rename"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <AppBarButton
        Icon="Pin"
        Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton
            Icon="Clear"
            Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}"
            Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <AppBarButton
            Icon="Delete"
            Style="{StaticResource PlaylistAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```

Best regards.

Comment: This can be a solution. But can I ask why resizing makes the more button appear?

Comment: Wait...Actually my Clear button and Delete button are optional, so they are not always visible. If I put them into the `SecondaryCommands`, the overflow button will still be there even if there is supposed be nothing.

Comment: This is the design of the CommandBar. You can understand that when the width is narrowed, the overflow controls will be automatically moved into the `SecondaryCommands`, so that the overflow button will be displayed because the `SecondaryCommands` are not empty. As for the button you said is optional, I think you can adjust the display of the Overflow button by adjusting the `CommandBar.OverflowButtonVisibility` when the state changes.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But actually the overflow button shows up immediately when I resize the window larger/smaller even by a little. I just don't get why resizing a little makes it appear.

Comment: The process of overflow button is dynamic. When you try to enlarge the width of the software, `CommandBar` will judge whether the current control width can accommodate the button. You may wonder why the software width is enlarged immediately after the overflow button appears, but the button does not appear immediately. This is because the button width predicted by the `CommandBar` at this time should actually be the width of the `FlyoutItem` in the `SecondaryCommands`, which may be wider than the actual button, which leads to inconsistent behavior.